# TypeError due to 'undefined' value discrepancy with console.log showing prop having value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, typeerror

I have a component that I'm writing, within which I want to display a [material-ui Drop Down Menu](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dropdown-menu) populated by some dynamic content (passed into the component as a prop). Here is the code for the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import DropDownMenu from 'material-ui/DropDownMenu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import CircularProgress from 'material-ui/CircularProgress';

const style = {
  box: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: 8
  },
  currentTermText: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 18,
    marginRight: '10px'
  }
};

const TermSelect = ({ terms, currentTerm, changeTerm }) => (
  <div style={style.box} >
    <div style={style.currentTermText}>Term:</div>
    {terms && currentTerm ?
      <DropDownMenu value={currentTerm} onChange={(event, index, payload) => changeTerm(payload)}>
        {terms.map((term) => {
          console.log(term.id);
          return (
            <MenuItem key={term.id} value={term.id} primaryText={term.term} />
          );
        })};
      </DropDownMenu>
      :
      <CircularProgress />
    }
  </div>
);

TermSelect.propTypes = {
  terms: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.object),
  currentTerm: React.PropTypes.string,
  changeTerm: React.PropTypes.func
};

export default TermSelect;
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at DropDownMenu.js:265
    at forEachSingleChild (ReactChildren.js:52)
    at traverseAllChildrenImpl (traverseAllChildren.js:69)
    at traverseAllChildrenImpl (traverseAllChildren.js:85)
    at traverseAllChildren (traverseAllChildren.js:164)
    at Object.forEachChildren [as forEach] (ReactChildren.js:72)
    at DropDownMenu.render (DropDownMenu.js:264)
    at ReactCompositeComponent.js:793
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:74)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (ReactCompositeComponent.js:792)
```

And here is the line of code at DropDownMeu.js:265:

```
    if (child && value === child.props.value) {
```

Which suggests that the props to my `MenuItem` components are being interpreted as `undefined`. However, the console output, just above this error, shows this:

```
TermSelect.jsx:25 4640
TermSelect.jsx:25 4630
TermSelect.jsx:25 4620
TermSelect.jsx:25 4610
TermSelect.jsx:25 4600
TermSelect.jsx:25 4590
TermSelect.jsx:25 4580
TermSelect.jsx:25 4650
```

Those 4**0 numbers (actually strings) are the expected values of the console.log and shows that `term.id` is indeed not undefined as the error seems to suggest. Why is this error being thrown?

I have tried replacing the Drop Down Menu with a [Menu](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/menu) and the same error occurs, but removing the Drop Down Menu altogether and just displaying the mapped Menu Items on their own works.

Thanks!

Comment: Learn to interpret error messages: `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` - this clearly shows that `props` is `undefined`.

Comment: I've updated the title to better reflect my confusion.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I don't understand your comment here - it's happening in material-ui not in OP's own code.

Comment: Can you share your code to the component where you are passing in the prop values? It looks like it's looking for a property value that doesn't exist yet.

If it is something that should update after a certain user actions/inputs, you need to use `componentShouldUpdate()` to properly pass in the right value.